# [mac os]-bash: grunt: command not found

Tags: gruntjs

No matter which grunt I install, like,

> sudo npm install -g grunt

or

> sudo npm install -g grunt-cli

I always get '-bash: grunt: command not found' in my Macbook.

Does anybody know who can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Check out the getting started guide for how to setup grunt - http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Comment: Check if grunt exist $. which grunt